# How to display text with mode "TailTruncation" of Editor on Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm designing a layout as [iMessenger](https://developer.apple.com/imessage/) of `iPhone`.

At Textbox, I use [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor) to input text.

On [iMessenger](https://developer.apple.com/imessage/) app of `iPhone`, `Editor` can display with mode `TailTruncation`

[image: iMessenger1]

========================

[image: iMessenger2]

I searched and found no properties of `Editor` similar to [LineBreakMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.linebreakmode?view=xamarin-forms) of `Label`.

How to display text with mode `TailTruncation` of `Editor` on `Xamarin forms`?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) on your [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor) to implement `TailTruncation`.
Something like this:

```
public class FullToShortConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string fullText = (string)value;
            string tempString = "";

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullName)) {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if (parameter == null) { // You can pass desired string length as a parameter
                // Assuming you want a string of length 10. 
                // Then 0..6 is 7 chars + three dots
                // There is no sense in changing the last 3 letters with ellipsis
                tempStr = fullText.Length > 10 ? fullText.Substring(0, 6) + "..." : fullText;
            } else {
                int maxChars = (int)parameter;
                tempStr = fullText.Length > maxChars ? fullText.Substring(0, maxChars - 3) + "..." : fullText;
            }

            return tempStr;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Should never come here");
        }
    }
```

You would then need to handle this in `Focused` and `Unfocused` events, if you wanted to display/hide full text when user is interacting with the editor.

Comment: How to handle `parameter `? If we handle it in `Focused` and `Unfocused` events, how to could do it?

Comment: I have found a solution: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48063/how-to-pass-converterparameter-to-a-binding-when-using-setbinding-in-code

Comment: Code: `Binding binding = new Binding("Text", BindingMode.OneWay, fullToShort, 255, null, chatTextInput);`

            `chatTextInput.SetBinding(Editor.TextProperty, binding);`